# Error in building Sencha Touch 2 application

Tags: javascript, list, load, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

While I am building my sencha touch 2 app using the command:-
 **sencha app build production**

but it throws an error:

```
[INFO] Deploying your application to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iPadapp/build/production
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/loading
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[ERROR] Error thown from your application with message: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object
```

I traced the error in my code . I found out , it is due to loading my list. Here is my code

```
Ext.define("myProject.store.Members",{
    extend  :'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:"Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage",
    config: {
        model   :"myProject.model.Member",
        sorters :'lastName',
        autoload:true,

        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id  : 'mainStore'
        } 
    }
});
```

if I remove the line 'autoLoad: true' ( which breaks my application, then I can build the application. But my list is not loading. If I put it back the error repeats. I tried dynamically loading the list with load function , but it does not make any sense.

And here is the model.js file I amusing.

```
Ext.define('myProject.model.Member', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'index',                 
            'email',
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'phone',
            'currentemployer',
            'currenttitle',
            'interestlevel',
            'tcgroupNames',
            'active',
            'lastlogin',
            'usertypedesc',
            'recruiternotes',
            'recruitercontact',
            'addtype',
            'usertypedesc',
            'jobtitle',
            'ipAddress',
            'recruitersource',
            'agentkeywords',
            { name: "created", type: 'date' },
            'recruiterprofileurl_linkedin',
            'recruiterprofileurl_facebook'
        ]
    }
});
```

Any Help is appreciated

Happy coding to all

Comment: Are you running this on a local http server ?

Comment: Yes I am using Apache HTTP server. But I am not making any remote server interactions. Its only a local storage.

Comment: can you paste the model.js file ?

Comment: hi @Disco , I have edited the question with model.js file.

Comment: What OS are you running? I tried setting up a clean project using localStorage with `autoLoad` set to true and everything works and builds for me fine. Zip of the project here: http://rwd.me/GZ4P

Comment: Uhm... lastName !== lastname. I hesitate to pose this as an answer, but I -think- that you would get that 'undefined...' because you capitalized wrong.

Comment: @Disco yeah but how to run this application on eclipse phonegap build?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue, the command builder isn't allowed to open a connection to localstorage so it crashes.

You should be able to set `Ext.getStore('Members').setAutoLoad(true);` in the 
`launch: function () {` of `app.js`.

Then your app will build and should still load the data into the store.

Comment: Hi Adam , I have tried it but no change. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Anyway, is it such a big problem to load the store manually to get around this?

Comment: @adam marshall, Why should the sencha command access the localstorage? This doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: This worked for me. heyjii, be sure to set autoLoad: false in your store and make sure no other errors are present, it should work.

Comment: @borck the sencha command loads the webpage with a file:// protocol the localStorage api isn't available to the file:// protocol its a browser security measure.

Comment: @AdamMarshall So you mean, the sencha command actually loads the webpage to determine the dependencies? I was thinking it was just a parsing involved... Now I get why it's failing, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does load a webpage. However, this works fine for me - which makes no sense (because your theory about security makes sense). I have created a new project which demonstrates it working fine: http://rwd.me/GZ4P

Comment: @rdougan Which version of sencha command are you using? Your example project doesn't build for me using 'sencha app build production' throws: '[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[ERROR] Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Note that tracing an error is better when using Chrome developer tools than using Firebug,
becuase in the console of Firebug it shows no exceptions, while on the console 
of the Chrome developer tools it shows the uncaught exception:

```
Ext.getStore("Notes").load();
```

where the store 'Notes' doesn't exist in my case.